# MongoDB C++ Driver Compile Error

Tags: mongodb, visual-c++

Try to work with MongoDb driver on VS 2010.
After include the fresh compiled MongoDB driver (nightly) using boost 1.4.9
have this error :

mongoclient.lib(1): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: '<'

mongoclient.lib(2): error C2018: Unbekanntes Zeichen '0x60'

mongoclient.lib(3): error C2059: Syntaxfehler: 'Ungültiges Suffix für Zahl'

mongoclient.lib(3): error C2018: Unbekanntes Zeichen '0x16'

............
fatal error C1003: Mehr als 100 Fehler gefunden; Kompilierung wird abgebrochen.

Answer (score 0):

It is strongly recommended that you don't use the stand alone driver.  Rather download and build the full mongodb source from git.  This should get you the driver and header files (I don't have a windows box to test this with but this is true for OSX/Linux and the recommended solution for all platforms).  Finally, link the library, don't include the .cpp file.

Best,
Charlie